# Resharper vs Borland Devpartner for visual studio

Tags: resharper, devpartner

What are advantages of using Borland Devpartner over resharper or vice-versa? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developers working on DevPartner Studio.  Frankly, I'd never heard of Resharper before, and after googling on it I found out why: it appears to be mainly for use with C# (hence the "sharp").  DevPartner Studio is a collection of tools originally written independently, and then integrated into Visual Studio.  Most of these tools were written before C# and .NET came into existence, and are focused mainly on the native C/C++ world, not the managed C# world.  There is some support for managed code, but that is not where the product shines.

So, the answer to your question depends on what you are doing: native or managed code.